# Assembly Language Loop

Tags: loops, assembly

```
MOV AH,02H

MOV BH,00H 

MOV DH,0006H      

MOV DL,0030H      

INT 10H        


MOV AH,09H

MOV AL,00B3H

MOV BH,00H

MOV BL,70H

MOV CX,0001H

INT 10H
```

|
|
|
|

I want to display like this.. how to add loop?
I need to increment the DH by 1 every loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mov bx, counter

loop:
push bx

your code

pop bx
dec bx
jg loop
```

I save bx on the stack just in case, so you don't loose the counter while you do something else in between.